# Array . How do you add text at Index in List or Array?

Tags: c#, arrays

How do you add text at the end of all items in a List<> ?
Sorry If my question is confusing. I tried to edit it with desired output to make it clearer.

```
var hltv = new List<string>();
hltv.Add("How are you");
hltv.Add("What are you");
hltv.Add("Please stop");

foreach (var item in hltv)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm trying to add "doing" to the end of each item in hltv List.

So in the end I get the Output:

How are you doing
What are you doing
Please stop doing

Comment: Are you trying to modify the list or just print "doing" at the end of each sentence?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing, hence you're getting very different answers. Your title talks about an array, and adding something at a specific index. The body of your question doesn't mention an index at all. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Line Solution-

```
hltv = hltv.Select(eachItem => string.Concat(eachItem, ' doing')).ToList();
```

Comment: Thats work. Any idea also how to add it permanently to the List items?

Comment: I have updated it. [test](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8521245/test)

Comment: The code still won't compile, and calling `string.Concat` seems rather less readable than just `eachItem + " doing"`. You might also want to mention that this doesn't modify the existing list, but creates a *new* list and assigns a reference back to the original variable. That difference may be crucial if other code as a reference to the original list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) extension method as follows:

```
var hltv = new List<string>();
hltv.Add("How are you");
hltv.Add("What are you");
hltv.Add("Please stop");

hltv = hltv.Select(item => item + " doing");

foreach (var item in hltv)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't modify the list, which I *suspect* is what the OP wants. I would suggest waiting until the question is a lot clearer before answering though.

Comment: @JonSkeet out of curiosity, what makes you suspect that? It seems like the question doesn't care about means, but an end (to me).

Comment: @ap: The comment of "Thats work. Any idea also how to add it permanently to the List items?" on Vikash.777's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it in the List item just make a function that return a string

```
    private string addDoing (string text)
    {
retrun text+" doing" ; 
};
```

then u can call it like that:

```
hltv.Add(addDoing("Please stop"));
```

or if you want to just output on the console without saving it in the list just:

```
  foreach (var item in hltv)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(addDoing(item));
            }
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

good old `for` does the trick

```
var l = new List<string>();
l.Add("test 1");
l.Add("test 2");

for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++ )
{
    l[i] = l[i] + " doing";
    Console.WriteLine(l[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hltv = new List<string>();
        hltv.Add("How are you");
        hltv.Add("What are you");
        hltv.Add("Please stop");

        foreach (var item in hltv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item+ " doing");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```